# Add product to cart outside of magento (external script)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have to add a product through an external page into the cart under the same URL.

The difference between these pages is that e.g. `test.de` is running TYPO3 and `test.de/Shop` is running Magento and `test.de/productpage` is running an external script through TYPO3.

From the product page, I have to add a product to the Magento cart to proceed the checkout.

The key problem is to start the session outside of Magento. 
If I call `test.de/Shop/checkout/cart` before I go to`test.de/productpage` and add a product to the cart, it works flawlessly.
But if I go the normal way (site -> productpage -> cart) I cant get Magento to listen to the session on the product page.

I have something like this to call

```
function addToBasket()
    {

        require_once('../app/Mage.php');
        ob_start();
        session_start();
        umask(0);
        session_write_close();
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(33);

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));   

        $productId = !isset($_GET['activeProdId']) ? '' : $_GET['activeProdId'];
        $qty = !isset($_GET['qty']) ? '1' : $_GET['qty'];

        if(empty($productId)) {
            return "no product-id found";
        }

        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

        $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();

        $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));

        $session->setLastAddedProductId($product->getId());
        $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        $cart->save();

        return true;

   }
```

The addToBasket is called through ajax.

So the question is: How do I start the session outside of the Magento-scope and put products into the cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add first (like *@samsonovits* suggested) I had to add the store code in mage app and the store id (didn't test if the store-id is necessary after adding the store code).

```
Mage::app("default")->setCurrentStore(33);
```

Afterwards I called the frontend on `Mage::app`

```
Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
```

I switched the `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')` to the singleton `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')`.

Since `Magento 1.8` we have to add a `form_key` to add products through an external script.

This was accomplished by the following code:

```
$param = array('product' => $productId,
                   'qty' => $qty,
                   'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey());      

$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
```

Now we could proceed with a `$cart->addProduct($product, $request)` and `$cart->save()` to save the cart.

There is one more important part to change (since the external script is not in the same scope like magento) - the cookie url and path.

> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Cookies

There we have to customize two fields:

`Cookie-Path: /Shop` (where `/Shop` is the destination of magento)

`Cookie-Domain: .test.de` (where `.test.de` is the URL of the project)

After this the `/Shop/checkout/cart` was able to inherit the `frontend-Cookie` of the external script (`productpage`)

> **NOTE:** Without changing the Cookie-Path & Cookie-Domain Magento will create two frontend cookies with different content.

**Full code:**

```
function addToBasket()
{

    require_once('path/to/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app("default")->setCurrentStore(33);
    umask(0);
    Mage::app()->loadArea('frontend');
    $productId = !isset($_GET['activeProdId']) ? '' : $_GET['activeProdId'];
    $qty = !isset($_GET['qty']) ? '1' : $_GET['qty'];
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->setStoreId(33);

    $cart->init();

    $paramater = array('product' => $productId,
                        'qty' => $qty,
                        'form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey()
                );       

    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($paramater);


    if(empty($productId)) {
        return "no product-id found";
    }

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

    $cart->addProduct($product, $request);

    $session->setLastAddedProductId($product->getId());
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    $cart->save();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Although this is an old post. I'm facing a similar problem. I have a new php-page (https://www.scrapwebshop.nl/AddToCart.php?id=5100) which will get the form_key and then redirect to the correct url (https://www.scrapwebshop.nl/checkout/cart/add/...) But my form_key is different than the one used in the webshop. Making me think about your comment on the Cookies.
What should I use for values? My `Cookie-Path: /` and `Cookie-domain: scrapwebshop.nl`.  `AddToCart.php` will be called from my Facebook Store page. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - I can't help you. I hope someone else can help with this.

Comment: Thanks Slatyoo I figured it out. I needed to `$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");` as well, although I'm not using that variable at all. My full working script is at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249156/adding-addtocart-link-to-facebook-shopping-page

Answer (score 0):

once you include Mage.php you will need to initialize Magento with

```
Mage::app("default");
```

*(first param is store code)*

after that...

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
```

...will work as it should.

Comment: Already tried to add the store code but this wont change anything. Same issue as described.